# How to pass URL through activated route in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a button in my Ionic app in page1. Through this button, I'm making a call to a function called myfunc(item.url).

```
<ion-item (click)="myfunc(item.url)">
        <ion-label color="primary"> Click here! </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

The function for myfunc(item.url) is something like this:

```
myfunc(imageUrl:string) {
    this.nav.navigateForward('/page2/${imageUrl}');
}
```

Here I'm passing an url from page1 to page2 something in the format of http://example.com/xyz.

The problem that I'm facing is when I pass an url only `http:` is getting stored in the variable. That is I'm unable to get the entire url with forward slashes.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.receivedUrl = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('imageUrl');
    /* Expected Output: this.receivedUrl = "http://example.com/xyz" but 
       Obtained Output is: this.receivedUrl = "http:" */
}
```

Please help me get the entire url instead of just http: . Thank you in advance.

Comment: pass your image url in queryParams

Comment: @KajolChaudhary Can you provide me a sample code snippet as I'm new to ionic? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Encode Image Url before passing as url have special character due to which you are not able to get the whole image url

```
this.nav.navigateForward(`/page2/${encodeURI(imageUrl)}`);
```

Comment: this.router.navigate( ['/page2'] , { queryParams: { imageUrl: imageUrl }}); }  try this

Comment: this.nav.navigateForward(`/page2/?imageUrl=${encodeURI(imageUrl)}`);